# Squid cache issue

Tags: networking

I have a issue with my squid cache :

```
2017/12/13 11:31:46| ERROR: Can not open file /etc/squid/squid.adservers.regex for reading
2017/12/13 11:31:46| Warning: empty ACL: acl ads dstdom_regex -i "/etc/squid/squid.adservers.regex"
2017/12/13 11:31:46| ERROR: Directive 'header_access' is obsolete.
FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 3343: cache_dir ufs /CacheSquid 3 358 16 256
Squid Cache (Version 3.5.23): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.050 seconds = 0.040 user + 0.010 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 42192 KB
Page faults with physical i/o:
```

try to edit and now even worst

```
2017/12/13 11:35:51 kid1| ERROR: Can not open file /etc/squid/squid.adservers.regex for reading
2017/12/13 11:35:51 kid1| Warning: empty ACL: acl ads dstdom_regex -i "/etc/squid/squid.adservers.regex"
2017/12/13 11:35:51 kid1| ERROR: Directive 'header_access' is obsolete.
2017/12/13 11:35:51 kid1| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid
2017/12/13 11:35:51 kid1| Creating missing swap directories
2017/12/13 11:35:51 kid1| /CacheSquid exists
FATAL: Failed to make swap directory /CacheSquid/00: (13) Permission denied
2017/12/13 11:35:54 kid1| ERROR: Can not open file /etc/squid/squid.adservers.regex for reading
2017/12/13 11:35:54 kid1| Warning: empty ACL: acl ads dstdom_regex -i "/etc/squid/squid.adservers.regex"
2017/12/13 11:35:54 kid1| ERROR: Directive 'header_access' is obsolete.
2017/12/13 11:35:54 kid1| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid
2017/12/13 11:35:54 kid1| Creating missing swap directories
2017/12/13 11:35:54 kid1| /CacheSquid exists
FATAL: Failed to make swap directory /CacheSquid/00: (13) Permission denied

the issue might be witch webmin,
it's keep telling me cache directory not initialised, if I click initialled cache I then have

"Your Squid cache directories /hdd1, /ssd1, /hdd1, /ssd1, /hdd2, /ssd2, /hdd3, /ssd3, /hdd2, /ssd2, /hdd3, /ssd3 have not been initialized.This must be done before Squid can be run.
 Initialize Cache
```

"
with the same on the squid.conf, I don't know where this is coming from I don't have SSD / HDD just a MiniSD card...

Answer (score 2):

Solution sudo chown proxy:proxy /patch/to/cache -R

```
sudo chown proxy:proxy /CacheSquid -R
```

edit the squid.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

or, regarding your version of squid

```
sudo nano /etc/squid3/squid.conf
```

and uncomment

> cache_effective_user proxy